# How to move archived Outlook for Windows Files to Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office

I have some old archived Outlook for Windows files that I want to move to Apple Mail in order to look into some older files. I don't have any access to Windows systems, I run Apple Mail on my Mac Book Pro. I tried looking online for a solution but the methods explained the result in nothing. Seeking for help on this forum and hoping to find the best possible answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import PST files into Apple Mail, you have to convert the files. There are a plethora of converter programs on the Net, many are listed in this Apple Support Community post: (I did not find any of them to be free)

One that is listed on Apple's Site for performing the same is https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pst-converter-pro/id446401009?mt=12

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got PST Converter Pro. This is a very helpful tool. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Kevin, but Apple Mail doesn't support Outlook's .pst or .ost files; there's no direct way to import them into Mail.  There are, however, 3rd-party apps that will convert the files for you.

A quick search did turn this article up: https://www.macworld.com/article/2151263/importing-windows-outlook-messages-into-apples-mail.html

which may be useful to you.

Good luck!